# Correct way to use Model's method in codeIgniter's view?

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller, codeigniter-2

From my VIEW, let's call it 'index', on a button click I would like to perform a DATABASE QUERY ***without*** loading the page again , however I cannot think of a method to so without breaking the MVC principles.

The only think that comes to mind is extremely lame, using a javascript ajax call inside the view, but i know this is not the RIGHT think to do.

How can I approach this matter?

**Goal: Call a model's method without redirecting or reloading**

This is driving me insane, really, **I don't want the code answer per se**, what I want is  to know the **ACTUAL PROPER** to do this, following the MVC php principles.

Thanks community

Comment: AJAX *is* the right thing to do, why do you think it's not?  Use an AJAX call to call the controller with will call the model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make an AJAX call to the Controller which will call the appropriate Model's functions in order to do any kind of database queries and then you will echo the results of the Controller back to the View. You do not brake the MVC concept, you can check it below:

```
        View (AJAX call)
                ||
                ||----------> Controller
                ||               ||
                ||               ||------------> Model
                ||               ||               ||
                ||               ||<--------------|| 
(AJAX response) || <-------------||
```

Comment: Hi billy thanks for responding, I have a doubt, how does the controller return data afterwards? Do i have to "php echo" or is there a better way? Thanks.

Comment: Yes you just have to `echo`. Even better you could have a specific View to load just only the data responses from the Controller in which you will do the `echo` instead of the Controller.